# How do I get a P5.js image into the DOM?

Tags: dom, p5.js

I want to get an internally created image file within P5.js (not loaded or from a url) into the DOM. I’m sure it’s really simple, but have no idea, thanks.

Comment: Your question would benefit from more details: It doesn't really matter how you create the image as long as it's a p5.Image object you can use it the same way. So what do you mean by "an image file created within p5.js"? Can't you use the [`image()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image) function as you'd usually do? What do mean precisely by getting it into the DOM? You could share the relevant part of your code showing what you want to do.

Comment: hi - it's okay - I found the solution on this forum, thanks,
https://discourse.processing.org/t/how-to-get-a-p5-image-into-the-dom/25726/10

Answer (score 0):

```js
var img,src;
var imgh=new Image()
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  //draw something
  lsj(3, 3, 120);
  src=canvas.toDataURL()
  img=loadImage(src)
  imgh=select("#myimg")
  imgh.attribute('src', src); 
 
}
function draw(){
  background(frameCount%224,100)
  image(img,-frameCount%224,8)
  imgh.position(frameCount%524,8)
  
  
}
function lsj(k, l, n) {
  push()
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  stroke(0);
  noFill();
  for (let t = -n; t < n; t++) {
    ellipse(
      width/4 * cos((TWO_PI * k * t) / 150),
      height/4 * sin((TWO_PI * l * t) / 150),
      120,
      120
    );
  }
  pop();
}
```

```css
html,body{
width:100%;
margin:0,auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style="background-color:#ddd0;" id="myimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Ranunculus_glaberrimus_labelled.jpg/330px-Ranunculus_glaberrimus_labelled.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

```
var img,src;
var imgh=new Image()
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  //draw something
  lsj(3, 3, 120);
  src=canvas.toDataURL()
  imgh=select("#myimg")
  imgh.attribute('src', src); 
  frameRate(16)
}
```